# Can I return a function from methods property in Vue and use it as event handler?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can we do something like this in Vue or I have to use only arrow function.

```
<template>
<vue-component
 v-for="(data, index) in someArr"
 @someEvent="someMethodWrapper(data)" 
>
</vue-component>
</template>

<script>
 methods: {
  someMethodWrapper(data) {
   return (someotherData) => {
    this.setNewProperty = { [data]: someOtherData }
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected result? What is the role of someotherData?

Comment: @EstusFlask basically, I want to access the data emitted by vue-component in the returned function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-on` binding can accept either a function or an expression as event handler. A function that an expression evaluates to won't be used as event handler in this case.

This code just executes `someMethodWrapper` and ignores a function it returns. It could be workable by explicitly calling it:

```
@someEvent="someMethodWrapper(data)($event)"
```

At this point it doesn't serve a good purpose to make `someMethodWrapper` higher order function, it could change signature to fit the case better:

```
someMethodWrapper(someotherData, data) {...}
```

and

```
@someEvent="someMethodWrapper($event, data)"
```